# How to implement horizontal scroll bar as tabs grow

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to implement navigation tabs. As tabs grow beyond the limit, i need to provide a `horizontal` scroll bar.

My reference code:

```
http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/05/04/browser-like-tabs-with-angularjs-and-bootstrap/
```

I have implemented the same in the above url. But i need a horizontal scroll bar when the tabs grow more than the width. Presently it is coming below in a separate row.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

edit your ul and add two styles

```
  display:flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="display:flex;white-space: nowrap;">
```

Comment: I am using firefox. it looks it is working in chrome

Comment: It is working. But how can i make browser independent for these styles?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a fixed width and the set the css property overflow horizontal scrolling.

```
.nav {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 1500px;
}
```